# How to remove BOM from C# .net core web api JsonResult response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have simple .net core wep api application with contoller method like that

```
   [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult  Get(int id)
    {
        var myObj= _testRepository.TryGetById(id);
        if (myObj== null)
        {
            return new NotFoundResult();
        }
        return new JsonResult(myObj);

    }
```

`curl -ivs --raw` for this method returns json response with BOM symbols.

Response example:

```
92
{"id":767,"gender":"f","birth_date":-278121600}
0
```

How can I remove BOM from response?

**UPDATE**

Full response example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 26 Aug 2017 12:28:58 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

60
{"id":582,"place":"Площадь","country":"Япония","city":"Ньюква","distance":86}
0
```

where numbers **60** and **0** are not a BOM(my mistake here). They caused by [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding/).

Comment: What version of ASP.NET WebAPI and JSON.NET are you using? This behaviour is a bug and was fixed in 2014: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/577

Comment: I am using packages Microsoft.AspNetCore 1.1.2, Microsoft.AspNetCore,Mvc 1.1.3 and Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3

Comment: Don't worry about your English @Frank59, it seems fine to me. If you could avoid remarking about that in comments, that would be great - it doesn't really add to the question at hand, but it does give volunteer editors more work to do. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer, ok. i will try to avoid remark about my bad english skils=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark about BOM and `JsonResult` first:  `JsonResultExecutor` using `HttpResponseStreamWriter` which does not write a BOM regardless of the encoding used.

Now about chunked transfer encoding:

Most clients already remove the chunking and usually we no need worry about that.

Also there are some ways to disable chunking :

1. You can use `ContentResult` instead of `JsonResult` .

   ```
   public ActionResult  Get(int id)
   {
       var myObj= _testRepository.TryGetById(id);
       if (myObj== null)
       {
           return new NotFoundResult();
       }
       return new ContentResult{ContentType="application/json", Content=DoMySerialize(myObj)}; 

   }
   ```
2. You can fully buffer the response and determine the content-length. Here's a sample that buffers all responses in middleware
   https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/793a49fe111d86895f22300297fa70f710459406/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Buffering/ResponseBufferingMiddleware.cs#L19

Detailed comments available inside [question on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6719).